# Radon Nikodym derivative $\frac{\mathrm d(fλ)}{\mathrm d(gλ)}$

Tags: measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Here is the question:

> Consider the space $X = [0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure $\lambda$. Let $\mu = f\lambda$ and $\nu = g\lambda$ with functions $f$ and $g$ nonnegative, be finite measures. Find a condition characterising the absolute continuity $\nu \ll \mu$ and find the Radon Nikodym derivative $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\nu}{\mathrm{d}\mu}$.

On the first task, $\forall A \in \mathcal L [0,1]$, we have:

$$[\mu(A) = 0 \implies \nu(A) = 0] \iff \\
\big[\int_Afd\lambda = 0 \implies \int_Ag d\lambda = 0 \big] \iff\\
\big[f \chi_A = 0\ (\lambda.a.e)\implies g \chi_A = 0\ (\lambda.a.e) \big].$$

So on whichever sets $f$ is $0$ almost everywhere, g is also $0$ almost everywhere (w.r.t. $\lambda$).
Is this a good characterisation? Can you see a better one?

On the second task:

I can guess that we have $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\nu}{\mathrm{d}\mu} = \dfrac gf$. We have established in lectures the chain rule$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\nu}{\mathrm{d}\mu} = \frac{\mathrm{d}\nu}{\mathrm{d}\lambda} \frac{\mathrm{d}\lambda}{\mathrm{d}\mu} = g\frac{\mathrm{d}\lambda}{\mathrm{d}\mu}.
$$
Now I need an argument that justifies $\dfrac{d\lambda}{d\mu} = f^{-1}\ (\lambda. a.e.)$ "wherever $g \neq 0$". Not sure how to argue in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\supp}{supp}\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$For the first part, the characterization is fine, or it could be expressed as$$
λ(\supp(g) \setminus \supp(f)) = 0.
$$

For the second part, because $μ$ and $ν$ are finite measures on $[0, 1]$, then for any $A \in \mathscr{L}([0, 1])$,$$
\int\limits_A g \,\d λ = \int\limits_A \d ν = \int\limits_{[0, 1]} I_A \,\d ν = \int\limits_{[0, 1]} I_A \frac{\d ν}{\d μ} \,\d μ = \int\limits_A \frac{\d ν}{\d μ} \,\d μ = \int\limits_A \frac{\d ν}{\d μ} f \,\d λ.
$$
Thus $g = \dfrac{\d ν}{\d μ} f$ holds almost everywhere on $[0, 1]$, which implies $\dfrac{\d ν}{\d μ} = \dfrac{g}{f}$ holds almost everywhere on $\supp(f) \subseteq [0, 1]$.

Comment: Is there a similar statement for $\frac{d f_\# \lambda}{d g_\# \lambda}$, where $f_\# \mu := \mu \circ f^{-1}$ is the push-forward of $\mu$ by $f$?